MySQL prefix index on datetime column
I have a log table with timestamped (DATETIME) rows in the millions which I occasionally need to search by date or date range. I have an index on the timestamp column at present for the purpose.
However, I am wondering if it would be possibly to reduce the granularity of this index to, say, minutes or hours rather than seconds as a way of reducing the overall size of the index.
I have investigated prefix indexes, but these do not apply to DATETIME columns, so I am wondering if there is another way to do this. I am happy to trade a little in overall query performance if it can substantially reduce the size of my index.

"However, I am wondering if it would be possibly to reduce the granularity of this index to, say, minutes or hours rather than seconds as a way of reducing the overall size of the index." - Is the size of your index actually causing you problems?

Not particularly, but there are already multiple indexes on the table, with more likely, so every new index is another cut in the death of a thousand, so to speak! :-)

The size of a DATETIME is minimally 5 bytes, plus a variable amount for fractional seconds storage. Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-date-time
MySQL has no data type that represents a "rounded off" datetime value as you describe.
You could store DATE values with no time component, for 3 bytes per value.
Or you could transform a DATETIME to an INT value, for example 2024082217 (based on 2024-08-22 17:56:00 as I write this). This would use 4 bytes per value.
Honestly, I wouldn't worry about it. A DATETIME is already pretty compact as data storage goes.
If you find this is causing a problem, then either increase storage to fit the data you need, or else store fewer rows of data.
It's usually not worth spending a lot of effort for micro-optimizations, because they take time, make your project more complex, and risk creating more bugs.
It's not a good tradeoff. Even a few hours of a software developer's time to implement and maintain a custom solution is far more expensive than upgrading your storage.

Thanks Bill, that's a helpful analysis and I will stick with things the way they are.

Out of curiosity, I tried creating a both a simple index on the date field in question, as well as a functional index on the same column as follows:
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX ((DATE(mydatefield)));

Both indexes ended up being almost exactly the same size, which in hindsight seems intuitive enough - as much or more of the size of the index is taken up with the pointers to the matching records as will be taken up by the index keys - they just get grouped into larger buckets of less keys if you reduce the granularity of the key values.

A range query on an indexed DATETIME or TIMESTAMP is reasonably optimal.
For example
WHERE foo = 123
  AND dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
  AND dt  < CURDATE()

INDEX(foo, dt) will be much less efficient than INDEX(dt).
WHERE DATE(dt) = '2024-03-04'is terribly inefficient (even withINDEX(dt)`) because it is not sargable .
If neither of these examples fits your situation, let's see your query and SHOW CREATE TABLE.
